# .htaccess Force SSL Redirecting to /public_html

Tags: apache, .htaccess

The issue I am having is that after editing my .htaccess file to force all of my website's traffic to use an SSL connection, any visitors that do not put https:// in the domain name get redirected to https://www.iamjawa.co/public_html - A directory that is obviously not available. The code I have used to create the redirect in the .htaccess file is below.

How do I fix this?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your htaccess needs a RewriteBase

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I also had to test it with an incognito window, to see the changes. You can also clear the browser cache.